# Linked Lists in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a spreadsheet, I have multiple workbooks, I would like to sync the names in the first column between the workbooks, addition and removal.

is this posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer to this may be to make one workbook with just the list of values (I'll say "names" for an example), then the rest of the workbooks use that as a reference.  You only need to change each one once, but without a very complicated macro or script you won't get what you are after.

Think about it this way: Excel can have a cell be either a formula or a value.  If you only have 2 workbooks, you need to set one of the workbooks to get it's values from the other in a formula.  But, if  you change that second (formulaic) workbook to a declared value, the first won't get the change.  If you set them BOTH to be a formula, you don't have a start value.  You need to have a single location to edit that all your workbooks can read from, which means a separate "master" list in a distinct workbook.